# Change color of chart(graphic) when choose text in combobox

Tags: c#, charts, colors, series, graphic

I want to build graphic different color with conditions  in ms chart, and when i use this code, nothing happens. It's my code.

```
 if (metroComboBox3.Text == "Temperature")
        {

            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        //    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[0].Color = Color.Green;


            chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Green;
        }

        if (metroComboBox3.Text == "Relative Humidity")
        {
            chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            //    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[0].Color = Color.Green;
            chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Red;
        }
```

Comment: to you have a `databind` for your chart? Pls share more infos

Comment: no, i haven't databind

Comment: i show code, how i create chart in my answer

Comment: Well if you want to set a Color for a Series, the code is correct. So: what happens? Use the debugger to check if any of the conditions are true and the Color=.. lines get reached ! - Also: Do not put code in an answer, edit the question!!

Answer (score -1):

```
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[2].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        if (metroComboBox1.Text == "Text 1")
        {



            for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in metroGrid1.Rows)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    Int32.TryParse(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out x);

                    DateTime dt;


                    DateTime.TryParse(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out dt);

                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                    //Console.WriteLine(chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        if (metroComboBox1.Text == "Text 2")
        {........
```

Comment: it's how i create the chart

Comment: This is not an answer!  Do not put code in an 'answer', edit the question!!